# Saving Pandas series on existing excel worksheet

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to export some values from python to excel.
In the first part I want to setup the sheet and save it in a xlsx file.
After that I want to overwrite the same worksheet by adding a pandas series.

My issue comes from the fact that when I run my code, I obtain a brand new worksheet with the name 'Name1' instead instead of putting the Series on the existing sheet named "Name" previously.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#Page setup
wb = Workbook()
ws0 = wb.active
ws0.title = "Name"
ws0.sheet_properties.tabColor = "1072BA"
ws0['B1'] = "AAA"
wb.save('Example.xlsx')
wb.close()

#Insert pandas series on existing worksheet
path = r".\Example.xlsx"
book = load_workbook('Example.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

r1y = pd.Series([1,3,5,13,6,8])
df1y = pd.DataFrame(r1y)

df1y.to_excel(writer, 'Name', header=False, startcol = 0, startrow = 1)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First time since days in this forum, when someone can really copy+paste the code from the question and see it working! Congrats! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `to_excel` creates a new worksheet and does not want to write in an already created one. You are already having one, which is called `Name`, thus the new one is `Name1`. If you do not have a sheet `MyOwnName` this will crete one and write the data there:

```
df1y.to_excel(writer, 'MyOwnName', header=False, startcol = 0, startrow = 1)
```

Although I could not find anything mentioning it in the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-[docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: Thanks Vityata, unfortunately the issue remains. I checked the same documentation you linked me multiple times before and still no clue. Is there any other function other than "to_excel" that can help me to write the pandas series in an existing Worksheet?

Comment: @MattiaVicari - yes, the issue remains, it seems that the Panda treats `to_excel` as a export to a brand new worksheet.

Comment: @Vityala so there are no work around this issue? or other packages that just might do the job?

Comment: @MattiaVicari - As a workaround you can probably read the values from the newly generated sheet and write them to another sheet. XlsWriter is a library for this. See some examples - https://github.com/Vitosh/Python_personal

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this problem in a different website, which I report here.
I have not come up with this answer myself, so I want to credit who did:
https://cmsdk.com/python/insert-pandas-dataframe-into-existing-excel-worksheet-with-styling.html

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=["20-01-2018",4,9,16,25,36])
path = 'filepath.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = load_workbook(path)
**writer.sheets = dict((ws.title,ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)**
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Sheet1", startrow=2,index=False, header=False)
writer.save()
```

What did the job for me was the row highlighted in bold. I hope it can be of help to you!